# Python: Multiplying a dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

Hi I currently have 2 dataframe with different shapes

```
df11 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9

df12 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

a   b   c
0   7   8   9
```

I would like to multiply each row in df11 by df12. So the resulting dataframe should show

```
df13 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[7, 16, 27], [28, 40, 54], [49, 64, 81]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

    a   b   c
0   7   16  27
1   28  40  54
2   49  64  81
```

Comment: `df11*df12.iloc[0]` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using numpy multiplication

```
df13 = pd.DataFrame(df11.to_numpy()*df12.to_numpy(), columns=df11.columns)
```

Or you can use `pandas` mul operator like this,

```
df11.mul({'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9})
```

Comment: the drawback here is that is requires identical columns (number and order)

Answer (score 2):

One-liner

```
df_3 = df_1 * df_2.iloc[0]
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = {'a': [1, 4, 7],
          'b': [2, 5, 8],
          'c': [3, 6, 9]}
data_2 = {'a': [7], 'b': [8], 'c': [9]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

df_3 = df_1 * df_2.iloc[0]
print(df_3)
```

Output

```
    a   b   c
0   7  16  27
1  28  40  54
2  49  64  81
```

**Timings**
A few timings for this input.

```
# Paul_O's numpy approach
25.9 µs ± 440 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# iloc approach
172 µs ± 962 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# mozway's approach 
194 µs ± 254 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# Paul_O's mul approach
308 µs ± 1.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Making `data_1` a 10000 x 3 `DataFrame` of random integers between 1 and 10000 we get very similar results.

```
# Paul_O's numpy approach
39 µs ± 396 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# iloc approach
188 µs ± 1.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# mozway's approach
206 µs ± 2.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# Paul_O's mul approach
312 µs ± 1.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Of course, these are only two sets of timings for two very specific sets of input on one system so I would not advise on generating hard conclusions from these but it seems if your problem is very similar to this one then the `numpy` approach is best. The best way may differ in other circumstances, e.g., if the form of your input differs.

Comment: Yeah this is good if both data frame have the same column number and names. But what if my columns have different names?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
df13 = df11*df12.squeeze()
```

The potential advantage is that it would perform a 2D multiplication if df12 has more than 2 rows.

output:

```
    a   b   c
0   7  16  27
1  28  40  54
2  49  64  81
```